# Error: Given input "[object Object]" is not a number while sign transaction using web3

Tags: node.js, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

My tx variable is like below

```
let tx = {
    from: Deployers account address
    gas: 4700000
    data: contract.deploy({
          data: bytecode,
          arguments: ['string1','string2', unixTimestamp, ['array', 'of', 'strings']]
    }).encodeABI(),
    gasPrice: 10,
    nonce: nonceValue,
    chainId: blockchain_network_chain_id
    };
```

and I am signing a transaction using the below method of Web3.js using node.js

```
web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey), function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        return error
    }                                   
    if(data){
       return data
    }
});
```

but after signing, I am getting below error

**Given input "[object Object]" is not a number**